# MySQL procedure that create a log file / report?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to create MySQL procedure that return me some kind of report to file (log, anything).

For example I am in loop for each row in table. On each row I am checking if column 'name' contains char or if it's just null. Procedure is changing 'name' 1st char to upper, but if 'name' was null is reporting that 'Row 301 has no name'.

How to do something like that?

Comment: Take a look on IFNULL function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: Y i know that function, but how to deal with creating a log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use IFNULL for null fields, and take a look on this tutorial:

http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Export-Data/How-to-use-SELECT-INTO-OUTFILE-statement-to-export-data